# How to make an axum router handle return different content-type responses?

Tags: hyper, rust-axum

For example, when user access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello`, if query parameter `id` is 1, a plain text response return. If `id` is 2, give a json structure.

Summary:

| id (input) | status code | content-type | body |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | application/json | {"name": "world"} |
| 2 | 400 | text/plain | no such person |

```rust
struct HelloParam {
    id: u16,
}

struct HelloResponse {
    name: String,
}

async fn hello_get(Query(params): Query<HelloParam>) -> Response {
    // how to implement it? 
}

let router= Router::new().route("/hello", get(hello_get));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the examples at the beginning of the [`response`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/response/index.html) module. Axum gives you a bevvy of different ways to return data so that the Content-type header is automatically set appropriately.

(This seems like a homework question to me, so I'm not going to write your function for you exactly.)

For example, if you return a `String` as a body, the Content-type will automatically be set to "text/plain":

```rust
use axum::response::{IntoResponse, Response};

async fn returns_string() -> Response {
    String::from("Hello, world!").into_response()
}
```

There is also a custom `Json` struct for returning as JSON (with the Content-type header set appropriately) any type that implements `serde::Serialize`.

```rust
use axum::response::{Json, IntoResponse, Response};
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Hello {
    name: String,
}

async fn returns_json() -> Response {
    let hello = Hello {
        name: String::from("world"),
    };

    Json(hello).into_response()
}
```

So we can write a function that could return either type of response based on some property of the request. Let's choose based on the value of the "Accept" header:

```rust
use axum::{
    http::{
        header::{ACCEPT, HeaderMap},
        status::StatusCode,
    },
    response::{Json, IntoResponse, Response},
};
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Hello {
    name: String,
}

async fn heterogeneous_handle(headers: HeaderMap) -> Response {
    match headers.get(ACCEPT).map(|x| x.as_bytes()) {
        Some(b"text/plain") =>
            String::from("Hello, world!").into_response(),
        Some(b"application/json") => {
            let hello = Hello {
                name: String::from("world"),
            };
            Json(hello).into_response()
        },
        _ => StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST.into_response(),
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. But can you show me how to use query parameter as the parameter of `heterogeneous_handle()`. I can not compile it if I use Query<HelloParam> as argument.

Comment: Axum handler functions work by matching on their arguments as [extractors](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/extract/index.html#request-body-limits). Having the `Query(params): Query<HelloParam>` argument in your function signature means that it will handle requests with `name=value` pairs that match the members of `HelloParam`. So if a request comes in with a query string `?id=1`, your handler function will be called with `params` as a struct of type `HelloParam` with the values set accordingly. You can then just match on the value of `query.id` instead of the value of `headers.get(ACCEPT)`.

Comment: thank you very much. but compile error is:  the trait bound `fn(Query<HelloParam>) -> impl Future<Output = Response<http_body::combinators::box_body::UnsyncBoxBody<axum::body::Bytes, axum::Error>>> {heterogeneous_handle}: Handler<_, _>` is not satisfied
the trait `Handler<T, ReqBody>` is implemented for `Layered<S, T>`rustcE0277
libtest.rs(206, 45): required by a bound introduced by this call
method_routing.rs(141, 16): required by a bound in `axum::routing::get`.

Comment: Axum gives pretty inscrutable error messages sometimes. If you can edit your answer with what you've tried, I might be able to help you.

Comment: async fn heterogeneous_handle(Query(params): Query<HelloParam>) -> Response {
        match params.class.as_ref() {
            "json" => {
                let person = Person {
                    name: "world".to_string(),
                };
                Json(HelloResponse::Success(person)).into_response()
            }
            "text" => {
                "world".into_response()                
            }
            _ => StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST.into_response(),
        }
    }

Comment: Can you edit that into your _question_ so it's comprehensible?